# "Fill in" or "enter" the text fields

Tags: verbs

In the documentation file I am working on right now, I have to inform user about filling some optional and mandatory text fields.

Which verb better describes the "putting some text in the field" - "fill in" or "enter"?
Here are two examples:

1. In the newly opened Add Currency window (see Picture 4) fill in Name and Short Name fields and put a check mark next to Default currency checkbox (if required).
2. In the newly opened Add Currency window (see Picture 4) enter Name and Short Name fields and put a check mark next to Default currency checkbox (if required).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe use of *enter* is encouraged by filling in and then pressing the [Enter] key, or in web page era, the [Submit] "button".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either *enter text into the fields*

or

*fill the text fields*

*entering* is what you do to the text.

*fill* is what you do to the text field.

Comment: I agree.  You fill in a text field by entering text into it.

Answer (score 2):

I think *enter* better describes "putting some text in the field" rather than using *fill in*.

Answer (score 0):

I am reluctant to answer on such an old post, I seldom take joy in raising things of this nature from the dead; however, I stumbled upon it and I suppose it's still relevant.

A lot of words are passable for this scenario: input, enter, fill, insert, etc.

"Input user credentials"
"Enter username and password"
"Fill in the required text fields"
"Complete the form to proceed"
"Insert thyne response via your preferred input apparatus to unlock the eloquent mysteries of the number 42"

They all work and in terms of "best" it's irrelevant as stated in the accepted answer.

That said, as of late, I've been documenting restrictive states instead of trying to offer direction, e.g. "The username text field is required"

I feel this is more concise and direct. Instead of attempting to give the user/reader direction as to how to proceed, inform them of the limitations they may encounter and let them sort the "how."

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are okay, it depends on the context you are using it. *"fill in"* is more suitable for casual communication, in fact, you can also use *"fill out"* for the very same meaning.

So, I would go with one of these two ways:

*Fill in the text fields.*

or

*Fill out the text fields.*